# Finding the existence of solutions for system of equations prior to evaluation

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, systems-of-equations, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

## Problem

There exists a number such that it consists of two components and can be expressed as a sequence:
$$
N=n(a_{0}+a_{1})+a_{1},n∈ \mathbb{N}
$$
The task is to find a smallest value of N for a system of equations that are like system of congruences as such:
$$
a = \{a_{0}, a_{1} \}, \space b = \{b_{0}, b_{1} \}, \space c = \{c_{0}, c_{1} \} \\~\\
f(a,b,c)= N, where
\begin{cases}
N=n_{0}(a_{0}+a_{1})+a_{1} \\ 
N=n_{1}(b_{0}+b_{1})+b_{1} \\
N=n_{2}(c_{0}+c_{1})+c_{1} \\ 
\end{cases}
$$
Notice, any $ n $ is unknown. This problem is related to CRT, LCM and GCD. I am aware of that.

## Question

The problem lies in the fact that values of $ a_{1}, b_{1}, c_{1} $ can be $ 0 $ and co-prime. I have an algorithm which already calculates N based on these criteria. However, I have a problem with efficiently figuring out if a system has no solution. For example
$$
\begin{array}{lcl} 
f( \{70,5\}, \{160,3\})  & = & 4370 \\
f( \{70,5\}, \{160,3\}, \{101,2\} )  & = & 237005 \\
f( \{70,5\}, \{160,3\}, \{108,2\} )  & = & No \space solution \\
\end{array}
$$
My question is whether there exists an efficient method of figuring out whether the solution exists for $ f(a,b,c,d,e ...) = N $ without needing to iterate through very large numbers.

Comment: I am confused because $75$ does not divide $4370-5$. What do I miss ?